# Getting process base address in Mac OSX

Tags: macos

I'm trying to read the memory of a process using `task_for_pid` / `vm_read`.

```
uint32_t sz;
pointer_t buf;
task_t task;
pid_t pid = 9484;
kern_return_t error = task_for_pid(current_task(), pid, &task);
vm_read(task, 0x10e448000, 2048, &buf, &sz);
```

In this case I read the first 2048 bytes.

This works when I know the base address of the process (which I can find out using gdb "info shared" - in this case `0x10e448000`), but how do I find out the base address at runtime (without looking at it with gdb)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering my own question. I was able to get the base address using `mach_vm_region_recurse` like below. The offset lands in `vmoffset`. If there is another way that is more "right" - don't hesitate to comment!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mach/mach_init.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <mach/mach_vm.h>

 ...

    mach_port_name_t task;
    vm_map_offset_t vmoffset;
    vm_map_size_t vmsize;
    uint32_t nesting_depth = 0;
    struct vm_region_submap_info_64 vbr;
    mach_msg_type_number_t vbrcount = 16;
    kern_return_t kr;

    if ((kr = mach_vm_region_recurse(task, &vmoffset, &vmsize,
                 &nesting_depth,
                 (vm_region_recurse_info_t)&vbr,
                 &vbrcount)) != KERN_SUCCESS) 
    {
        printf("FAIL");
    }
```

Comment: Super useful snippet for a very undocumented function.

Comment: From the command line this can be useful:
sample $pid 1 2>/dev/null | grep "Load Address"

Answer (score 6):

Since you're calling current_task(), I assume you're aiming at your own process at runtime. So the base address you mentioned should be the dynamic base address, i.e. static base address + image slide caused by ASLR, right? Based on this assumption, you can use "Section and Segment Accessors" to get the static base address of your process, and then use the dyld functions to get the image slide. Here's a snippet:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include </usr/include/mach-o/getsect.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include </usr/include/mach-o/dyld.h>
#include <string.h>

uint64_t StaticBaseAddress(void)
{
    const struct segment_command_64* command = getsegbyname("__TEXT");
    uint64_t addr = command->vmaddr;
    return addr;
}

intptr_t ImageSlide(void)
{
    char path[1024];
    uint32_t size = sizeof(path);
    if (_NSGetExecutablePath(path, &size) != 0) return -1;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < _dyld_image_count(); i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(_dyld_get_image_name(i), path) == 0)
            return _dyld_get_image_vmaddr_slide(i);
    }
    return 0;
}

uint64_t DynamicBaseAddress(void)
{
    return StaticBaseAddress() + ImageSlide();
}

int main (int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    printf("dynamic base address (%0llx) = static base address (%0llx) + image slide (%0lx)\n", DynamicBaseAddress(), StaticBaseAddress(), ImageSlide());
    while (1) {}; // you can attach to this process via gdb/lldb to view the base address now :)
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, apologies for the noob question -  I tried adding this code into a new C file I added inside a dylib file I have created that attaches to an app I have made but I couldn't get any output in the console - should it be in a C++ file instead? I tried both but I get some build errors. Would this work in a dylib in this way? Any tips would be appreciated!