# Ruby: Obtaining a process load address for mach-o?

Tags: ruby, debugging

Does anyone know if there is a library that provides the functionality to obtain a processes base/load address? I would like to programmatically add breakpoints using Ragweed, however I only have the breakpoint offsets exported from IDA. The only thing I could find was:

[Getting process base address in Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301542/getting-process-base-address-in-mac-osx)

Answer (score 0):

Via Ragweed (https://github.com/tduehr/ragweed)

```
x = Ragweed::Debuggerosx.new(pid)
x.attach
puts x.region_info(0).base_address
```